# Vertical align center of absolute div

Tags: css

I have this simple HTML code, but make me frustrated because it can't center vertically :

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Hello World
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my CSS :

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 350px;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%
}
```

the `.inner` div is really center vertically, but based on top side of it. because of `top: 50%`, what I want is this `.inner` div really centered vertically on top of `.outer`. how to do that?

Comment: Just add `margin-top: -50px;` http://jsfiddle.net/wzjvmcLd/ this only works on fixed heights. I added background colour so you can see how centered it is. If you don't have background colour it won't looked centered since you only have a little bit of text

Comment: Just to clarify, in your circumstance, where heights of both divs are explicitly known, use `top: 50%; margin-top: -(height/2)px;` on your absolutely positioned div, or, in this case: `margin-top: -50px;`

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the height of both elements you can set your top to `top: 125px;`

(350 - 100) / 2.

**UPDATED WITH JQUERY**
http://jsfiddle.net/yf0ncd7f/

Comment: hi bro, what if the inner div's height is unknown. I mean, what if it's a paragraph with variable content? is there any way to automate your calculation?

Comment: If you're happy using jQuery then it would be achievable that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can center your element using css3 even if you don't know the dimensions.

```
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by line-height property set it to the height of the div as in your code it should be `line-height: 100px;`

```css
.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 350px;
    background: gray;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Hello World
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this CSS trick to make the div vertically centered (and optionally horizontally as well). This works for a parent div of any height and width, as long as they are specified.

```
.inner {
    position:absolute;

    // The height and width of the element have to be set for this to work
    height:100px;
    width:100px;

    // Setting the top and bottom to 0px as well as the margins to auto
    // causes the div to be centered vertically.
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;

    // To also center the div horizontally, do the same for
    // left, right and the margins.
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

**Note** that this solution only works when the height of the parent div is known beforehand and is specified. So the parent element needs to have `height:100px` or whatever amount of pixels you need it to be. Also the height can't be percentual, meaning that if the height of the parent div is declared as `height:50%`, this will **NOT** work.

The inner div can actually have a

Answer (score 1):

Actually an easy way to center a absolute div is to use margin: auto;

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  
  background: #eee;
}
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added borders to differentiate clearly
Is this you want?

http://plnkr.co/edit/JRct1x95gnIUl8jITzG0?p=preview

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  border : 1px solid #f00;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  border : 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

Comment: bro, what if the inner div has no height. I mean, what if the height is dynamic based on paragraph content?